# what to do? javascript array exercise

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, multidimensional-array, module

Find the correct passcode in the array and we'll do the rest. We can't disclose more information on this one, sorry.
Each entry in the first array represents a passcode
- Find the passcode that has no odd digits.
- For each passcode, show us the amount of even digits.
- If it has no odd digits, show us that you've found it and increase the number of terminals by one.

```js
var passcodes = [
 [1, 4, 4, 1],
 [1, 2, 3, 1],
 [2, 6, 0, 8],
 [5, 5, 5, 5],
 [4, 3, 4, 3],
];
```

so, i've tried almost everything i could think of. modulo, function, for loop and i can't seem to get it. i'm a beginner and this is an important exercise i have to do. but what do i do? it asks for the amount of even digits in each passcode, so i have to get the array within the array and then code something that i don't know to find even values. i'm stuck

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Think. And if it does not help at first, then think more. You will figure it out eventually.

Comment: What solution have you tried? Can you share it?

Comment: You don't understand the problem well enough. Solve it on paper first.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not really suitable for StackOverflow, you should at least try to write something and see how far you get.

Anyhow, you seem to want to iterate over the elements in *passcodes* to find the array with no odd numbers.

The first task is to how to determine if a number is even. That is as simple as looking for the remainder from modulus 2. If the remainder is zero, then the number is even, otherwise it's odd.

So a simple test is:

```
var isEven;
if (x % 2 == 0) {
  isEven = true;
} else {
  isEven = false;
}
```

Since 0 type converts to false, and the not (!) operator reverses the truthiness of values and converts the result to boolean, the above can be written:

```
var isEven = !(x % 2);
```

There are many ways to iterate over an array, if your task was just to find the element with no odd numbers, I'd use [*Array.prototype.every*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), which returns as soon as the test returns false, or [*Array.prototype.some*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which returns as soon as the test returns true.

However, in this case you want to count the number of even numbers in each element and find the first with all even numbers. One way is to iterate over the array and write out the number of even numbers in the element, and also note if its all even numbers. You haven't said what the output is expected to be, so I've just made a guess.

```js
var passcodes = [
 [1, 4, 4, 1],
 [1, 2, 3, 1],
 [2, 6, 0, 8],
 [5, 5, 5, 5],
 [4, 3, 4, 3], // this last comma affects the array length in some browsers, remove it
];

// Set flag for first element with all even numbers
var foundFirst = false;

// Iterate over each element in passcodes
passcodes.forEach(function(code) {

  // Count of even numbers in current array
  var evenCount = 0;
  
  // Test each element of code array and increment count if even
  code.forEach(function(num) {
    if (!(num % 2)) ++evenCount;
  });
  
  // If all elements are even and haven't found first yet, write out elements
  if (code.length == evenCount && !foundFirst) {
    console.log('Passcode (first all even): ' + code.join());
    
    // Set flag to remember have found first all even array
    foundFirst = true;
  }
  
  // Write count of even numbers in this array
  console.log('Even number count: ' + evenCount + ' of ' + code.length + ' numbers.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you meant ...but it does all what i could understand from your question. Hope it will help :)

```js
var passcodes = [
 [1, 4, 4, 1],
 [1, 2, 3, 1],
 [2, 6, 0, 8],
 [5, 5, 5, 5],
 [4, 3, 4, 3],
];

  
var aPassCode;
  while(aPassCode = passcodes.shift()){
    for(var i=0,evenCount=0,totalCount=aPassCode.length;i<totalCount;i++){
      if(aPassCode[i] % 2 == 0)evenCount++;
    }
    if(evenCount == totalCount){
      console.log('all digits even here: ' + aPassCode.join(','));
    }else{
      console.log(aPassCode.join(',') + ' contains ' + evenCount + ' even digits.');
    }
  }
```

Comment: this code works really well but I won't submit this answer to the exercise because I have to understand it really well and find an alternative way to this based on Codeacademy's way which is more baby steps otherwise my tutors would spot it right away, like "obviously she didn't do this on her own"